# how to configure asynconfig for lambda in cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I created a cloud formation stack as below, I'm setting  MaximumRetryAttempts: 1 , but once the function is created the retry events is always set to 2 ( attached screenshot) . how can i change the value of this.

```
HelloWorldLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: hello-world
      Runtime: python3.7
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
   version:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
     Properties:
       FunctionName: !Ref HelloWorldLambdaFunction
   asynconfig:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig
     Properties:
       FunctionName: !Ref HelloWorldLambdaFunction
       MaximumRetryAttempts: 1
       Qualifier: !GetAtt version.Version
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. However, it seems to me that you are viewing `$LATEST` version in the console.

However, you set the `asynconfig` for **version 1**. Thus, in the console you have to **explicitly select** the correct lambda function version:

[image]

#### Update

To use latest version:

```
  asynconfig:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref HelloWorldLambdaFunction
      MaximumRetryAttempts: 1
      Qualifier: $LATEST
```

Comment: thanks. can this be done with setting the version number. the only reason I added this line because -> Qualifier: !GetAtt version.Version, was because while uploading template it was complaining about not having qualifier attribute , I think.

Comment: @arve Hi. Yes, I updated the answer. Just use `$LATEST` for `Qualifier`.

Comment: that worked and I assume , when code executes , it always uses the latest version of the code ?

Comment: @arve Yes. the $LATEST is your current version that you see in the console by default.